# If A is both orthogonal and a orthogonal projector. What can you then conlcude about A?

Tags: linear-algebra

So this is an excercise.. Does anyone have a hint?

**If A is both orthogonal and a orthogonal projector. What can you then conlcude about A?**

I know that an $n\times n$ matrix $P$ is an orthogonal projector if it is both idempotent ($P^2 = P$) and symmetric ($P = P^T$ ). Such a matrix projects any given $n$-vector orthogonally onto a subspace (namely, the column space of $P$) but leaves unchanged any vector that is already in that subspace.

Furthermore, due to orthogonality: $A^TA=I$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very good.

So, if $P$ is in addition orthogonal, then
$P=P^2=P^TP=I$.

Answer (score 1):

It actually suffices to assume that $P$ is idempotent (instead of being a *orthogonal* projector) and $P$ is an orthogonal matrix: $P=P^TP^2=P^TP=I$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assume $P$ is diagonal...